# Jshint и jscs в VS2015

Tags: javascript, code-style, visual-studio-2015

Как подключить jshint и jscs к Visual Studio 2015 чтобы ошибки отображались в Error List'е?

Answer (score 1):

В текущей версии студии 2015 (и в релиз-кандидатной) это не работает, но обещают в последующих

[image: Mads Kristensen]